# Have a checkbox selection in jenkins in a matrix build

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-blueocean

Using Jenkins im trying to create multiple-input questions using checkboxes. Right now I have it working with a radio selection rather than checkboxes.

I'm using the scripted pipeline and cant change this.

Below is some code I have that creates the options but has radio buttons. It uses the matrix system to provide multiple questions and responses.

I also use Blue Ocean for the UI.

```
Map responseMatrix = [:]
stage("Choose combinations") {
     responseMatrix = input(
     id: 'Settings',
     message: 'Customize your matrix build.',
     parameters: matrix_axes.collect { key, options ->
     choice(
          choices: ['all'] + options,
          description: "Choose a single ${key.toLowerCase()} or all to run tests.",
          name: key)
     })
}
```

`matrix_axes` is a Map with key and value options, which contain the question and all possible options and is dynamically created. and shows this:

[image: Output]

Let me know any way to change this.

Comment: You can use this plugin [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on how to use Active Choices with a scripted pipeline? Cant find any documentation about this